# Google Analytics - a way to submit query from Query Explorer via API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

There is an API in place and available to me (v4 compatible), but for various reasons it's not working correctly and there is not much time to fix it (too many other fires). So the idea was floated that that to bypass most of the issues with API here it might be a quick-fix to send whole query to GA.

It needs to be automated and results stored in our DB (Webservice on MS Stack), else we would do it manually all the way, which is out of the question at this time.
Hence the question:

IS there a way to submit a query that is exactly the product of a Query Explorer via API or any other way and retrieve it's results?

Comment: If the api is not working for you why dont you ask a question about how to fix the issues you are having.   No you cant automate usage of the Query Explore its used for testing its not meant for production usage.

Comment: I don't want to automate query explorer, just to be able to use the query it produces via the API. I know what's wrong with our API, but not precisely and there's no time and manpower to fix it, thus we need some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The API Query URI returned by the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A78110423&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Ametric1
```

Is for the Google Analytics v3 api.  To use this in your own code you must simply attach a valid access token to the end of the request.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A78110423&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Ametric1&access_token=XXXX
```

This is not going to be using the Google Analytics v4 API that is a different call entirely.

Access tokens can be retrieved from either service account authentication or Oauth2 authentication and must be valid for the view you are requesting data for.

Comment: There is no information on how long the API v3 will be accepted by GA, so is there a similar process for v4? I mean - can it be translated or converted to v4 somewhow?

Comment: V2 hasn't been deprecated and neither has V3.  When it is you will have 1 -2 years to move to v4.   That request can not be translated to v4 the request is completely different   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples

Comment: You could try the [request composer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/request-composer/). It is not a general purpose tool but it does allow you to construct V4 type requests.

Comment: @Matt does request composer work with normal requests like stuff from v3?  No buckets or Histogram just dimensions, metrics and filters

Comment: Once [this pull request](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/pull/307) is accepted it will work for general requests and metric expressions. So if your are interested in speeding it along feel free to add any code review comments.